# Issues retrieving SharePoint Online Audit Data

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, auditing, spaudit

When I try to retrieve the Sharepointonline audit data using **search-unifiedauditlog** .For an particular site it seems to be getting only **pageview** where as other events are not able to be fetched Even though I haven't restricted to a particular event.

Additonally, it was able to fetch all details for another site of the same sitecollection.
Yes,I am admin of that site

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into the site collection settings and configure what events you want to audit.

Comment: Hi, I have enabled for all the events.otherwise.It won't be showing for the other site of the same sitecollection which I mentioned.

Comment: Have you checked the following: 1. Have you checked at the site or site collection level?  If not do so, now.  2.  How long ago did you enable the other events?  After you have checked my #1?

Comment: Hi, both are of same level.It was enabled for more than a week.Also..I was able to see the audits on security and compliance portal .